# Excel Formula Issue with variable cell reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a formula referencing a cell in another workbook.

```
='[Workbook2.xlsx]5683-4'!$C$23
```

The `5683-4` is a variable cell value in workbook 1 found at `A2`. How can I build a formula where the the formula changes based on the value of the `A` column?

For example:
If column `A3` is `5683-5` then the formula would populate

```
='[Workbook2.xlsx]5683-5'!$C$23
```

Comment: The only method is INDIRECT, but the drawback to INDIRECT is that the workbook being references must be open to get the values.

Answer (score 1):

If your formula is in Workbook1 and A3 contains the text name of a worksheet (i.e. "5683-5"), then this formula should do what you're looking for:

`=INDIRECT("'[Workbook2.xlsx]"&A3&"'!$C$23")`

The [`INDIRECT()` function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-indirect-function) returns a valid cell or range reference from a text string.  The formula above assembles the text string pointing to your other Workbook2 by concatenating the known parts (in quotes) with the variable part in A3.

Comment: Thank you to both of you. Bandersnatch's formula without = has worked but there is still one small issue. When I paste the formula, I have to double click the pasted formula then click enter for the new value to populate. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I figured it out. Issue resolved.Thank you again for your help